# Print pdf file to "Adobe pdf" printer using python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print a pdf file to the "Adobe pdf" printer from within python 2.7.5 script. By doing so, the file size is drastically reduced.

File name and path is:

pdfdoc = theDir + "\" + clientName + "-Stats.pdf"

Suggestions as to how to approach this?

I tried the following code but since it is printing to the "Adobe pdf" printer, I get a "save as" dialog box, which I don't want.

```
from subprocess import call

acrobat = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
pdfdoc = theDir + "\\" + clientName + "-Stats.pdf"
printer = "Adobe pdf"

call([acrobat, "/T", pdfdoc, printer])
```

Comment: To use Acrobat this way would require some way to specify an output pdf filename via some command line argument, yet there doesn't appear to be one. Adobe's own documentation says "You can display and print a PDF file with Acrobat and Adobe Reader from the command line. These commands are unsupported, but have worked for some developers." The "Adobe PDF" printer isn't the same thing as Acrobat although it comes included with it — and that is what is prompting you for a filename, not Acrobat itself. You might be able to do what you want using GhostScript.

Comment: Research seems to indicate that it cannot be done without using something such as GhostScript, which I want to avoid as this would require everyone who executes the script to install it on their computer.

Comment: I'm curious why the file size is drastically reduced.  If it is just because non-print elements of the PDF are removed, perhaps you could achieve the same result by passing it through a PDF library.  For example, [cat](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/cat.py) through [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw).  This is a library I wrote -- if it doesn't achieve a similar size reduction I'd be interested in looking at the original and compressed PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was to open Printer Preferences for the Adobe PDF driver (Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers) and manually set the Adobe PDF Output Folder. See screenshot below link to screenshot:

[Adobe PDF Driver Printer Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8opA.png)

I also deselected "View Results" but that's optional.

You may need to also rename the new PDF file. I accomplished this using shutil and renaming while moving the file to a different directory but you could also use os.rename(). I don't know how to access Adobe through Python to input the new filename during printing, but I suspect this is possible somehow.

Hope this helps.